# Movie about an alien/monster in Antarctica?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

So basically some scientists go to Antarctica but find a shape shifting alien but nobody knows who is real or not and in the end only two survive but they will probably die because they are stranded in Antarctica. Has anybody seen this movie and remembers the name of it?

Comment: [The Thing](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084787/) one of most famous films in the last 40 years.

Comment: @Tim: Why are you answering in the comments section?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why are you wearing that stupid man suit?  Wait, wrong film....

Comment: @Tim: 

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, as Tim already commented, it sounds a lot like [*The Thing* (1982)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_(1982_film)) with a group of scientists in Antarctica, a shape changing alien from another planet, and at the end only two are alive stranded in Antarctica without a base to keep them alive.  [Here's the IMDB page.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084787/)

*The Thing* (1982) is based on the novella ["Who Goes There?" (1938)](https://web.archive.org/web/20110723232143/http://nzr.mvnu.edu/faculty/trearick/english/rearick/readings/manuscri/Who%20Goes%20There/Who%20Goes%20There%20Index.htm) by John W. Campbell.

It is sort of a remake of *The Thing From Another World* (1951), and there was a sort of a prequel called [*The Thing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_(2011_film)) as well, made in 2011.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That’s the movie!

Comment: There is also a video game called "The Thing" which acts as a sequel. If that would interest anyone... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_(video_game)

Comment: And if you *truly* enjoyed The Thing, please consider reading [Peter Watts' The Things](http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/watts_01_10/).

Comment: @vahx As far as I can recall it's a truly abominable game though.

Comment: @Doomfrost Disagree, I played it many times. As a game it was a good game, lots of interesting game mechanics (such as freezing to death, gaining trust with NPC's, the smaller puzzles) as far as story goes, the first half is good, but once you got past the point that you got captured, the story became a bit cliche. Still overall a good game imo. Then again, its been like 10 years since I played it so my memory might just be giving me biased opinions from my childhood.

Comment: @vahx I won't challenge your childhood memories. There's enough of games that I loved which were really horrible by most standards that I'd be a hypocrite if I did. :) But The Thing really didn't do it for me (sadly). I think it might have been better experience on a console though. The porting to PC was kind of rushed as I remember. But everyone's experience is unique and if you enjoyed it you did. I won't rain on that parade.

Comment: for a question about the "sort of" remake, see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213358/black-and-white-film-where-monster-alien-gets-fried