# What was this black-and-white film set in the Arctic or Antarctic where the monster/alien gets fried in the end?

Tags: story-identification, movie, b-movies

Been trying to track an old black-and-white film I saw a long time ago. It was set in the Arctic or Antarctic and the research base was being stalked by an alien or monster.

The team eventually kill the creature by electrocuting it (I think) and turning it into a 'brussels sprout'.

I think it was a bit better than a B-movie but could be totally wrong.

Comment: Why is *brussels sprout* in scare quotes?

Comment: They are terrifying to me!

Comment: I'm confused. Did they *literally* get turned into sprouts (in the sense that someone said those exact words) or are these merely your own impressions of what they looked like; https://www.errenskitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/brussels-sprouts1.jpg

Comment: Also it wasn't literally a sprout but something like that, a small organic blob. It was B/W so couldn't tell if it was green. (Smile)

Comment: I originally read this as "alien gets fired" and wondered what it did to deserve that.

Comment: @Spencer kept making inappropriate comments about humanoids in front of the boss!

Comment: This is the evil that is Brussels sprouts https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=uM8lFtzrWfU

Comment: Another version of this film, much truer to the original 1938 short story ("Who Goes There?" by John W. Campbell, Jr.) was made in 1982. See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182198/movie-about-an-alien-monster-in-antarctica

Comment: We used to joke that this was the first Carrot Invader from Space!!!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Almost certainly Howard Hawks' **[The Thing from Another World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_from_Another_World)** (1951), which was remade by John Carpenter as *The Thing* in 1982.

It has the Arctic research base and the stalking monster, which is electrocuted at the end.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Klaus, should have known that. Thought I was called something _like *Artic base....*

Answer (score 33):

*The thing from Another World*? (1951)

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0044121/):

> Scientists and American Air Force officials fend off a bloodthirsty alien organism while at a remote arctic outpost.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_from_Another_World) has the ending being:

> The team retreat to the station's generator room to keep warm, and an electrical "fly trap" is rigged. The alien attacks again, but at the last moment, Carrington emerges and pleads desperately with it, attempting communication. **It knocks him aside, walks into the trap, and is electrocuted until it is reduced to ashes.**

---

Never seen it, but I knew there was a 50s movie (and earlier book) on which Carpenter's *The Thing* (1982) was based. And since this movie is the (or at least my) reference on "Alien in Antarctica movie", I figured it could be this...

Comment: You beat me by less than a minute!  :-)

Comment: That's the one. Feel like an idiot!!! Thanks Valorum for the clip. Was this were 'Watch the skies' came from or did they borrow it?

Comment: I've only seen the 1951 movie, but I have it on good hearsay that the 1982 version is much more faithful to the source material, so it seems likely that it was based on the "book" (John Campbell's classic novella "Who Goes There?") and not at all on the 1951 movie.